# Can't get Media Queries to Work

Tags: css, media-queries

I am trying to use media queries to make my layout responsive to the screen size. I'm just testing it out at the moment and I can't for the life of me get the method to work. I simply set up a media query that's supposed to change the background color of my links to red when the screen goes below 480px, but it just doesn;t work when I shrink my screen.

You can see this in action at http://www.noellesnotes.com

Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the relevent code:

HTML:

```
<div class="site-navigation">
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Work</a>
    <div class="site-title">Noelle Devoe</div>
    <a href="#">Blog</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.site-navigation a{
    width: 125px;
    float: left;
    padding: 50px 0 50px 0;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    transition:.5s;
    color: rgb(82,82,82);
}

.site-navigation a:hover{
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: rgb(242,168,134);
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
    text-shadow: rgb(200, 200, 200) 1px 1px 0px;
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    .site-navigation a{
        background-color: red;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your max-device-width to max-width

```
@media only screen and (max-width:480px){
  .site-navigation a {
        background-color: red;
  }
}
```

Should do the trick for you. Also a great page to look at is [the media queries page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Comment: @SajadLfc Edited, the code works though, I tested it on her site.

Comment: i also posted the same answer,but we both posted simultaneosly,and yet u had a syntax error,the voting was biased

Comment: @SajadLfc, soz bro.. Yes I had an extra bracket in there (thanks for pointing that out), but the main point was to change max-device-width to max-width.

Comment: np @Noelle, The site looks nice btw :)

Comment: That did the trick. And @SajadLfc, I voted after you posted your comment about biased voting, so I'm not sure why you'd say that... I didn;t mean to offend in any case.

Comment: @natewiley : i am talking about the upvotes(not your fault),some people are so biased

Comment: And thanks @natewiley. It's taking ages to figure out, so that means a lot!

Answer (score 2):

USE IT LIKE THIS:

```
   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){


}
```

this would be a good read http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/